# How do I do an 'and' search on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

Simple question really - the default search-method here is OR - ie a search for "apples oranges" will show posts that have either apples or oranges or both.
I want to show only posts that have both apples *and* oranges in them.

I tried "apples and oranges" but that returns the same as "apples oranges".

Surely there's a way to do exclusive search sets without resorting to the google-search?

Comment: This question would be better asked in meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You should ask it in Meta StackOverFlow

Comment: Cool - yes I realised this too late. I noticed some questions are 'moved' over there - is there a mechanism for that?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search

Comment: ChrisF - it is not quite a duplicate. The two matters are related, but my question is distinct. The other question asks why the 'OR" search is there by default - the fact that my answer can be found there is by side-effect... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a `+` before a search term means it *must* be included in the results, so the following produces a boolean `AND` search:

```
+apples +oranges
```

(this also works on quoted phrases, optional ninja options, etc.)

[You can test it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bapples%20%2boranges)

---

**Why don't we do `AND` by default?**

Well, we use `OR` searches by default and sort by relevance...so effectively you see `AND` results before `OR` results in the results that come up.  Compare the results above to [the `OR` version you get by default](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apples+oranges), see how the first results are the same?  That's because something with *both* terms is simply more relevant than anything that has just one.  So effectively (at least on the relevance sort), `AND` is a subset of `OR`, and it'd just be cutting the result list off at whatever the `AND` endpoint is...we'd rather give you all the relevant results and stick the stuff that *may* not be as matchy at the end.

Comment: Great answer here.

However a I recall (it was a while back) the results weren't the same. 

Try "ruby rails" vs "+ruby +rails" and the first results are actually sorted differently. I don't know why, because your answer about relevance makes sense...

Comment: this is now out of date: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange (yes I know it's your own post)