# Search [tag1] OR [tag2]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

Is there a way to search questions that are tagged with **either** tag1 or tag2?

Actually, I would like the general filter,

> ([tag1] AND [tag2], ...) OR ([tag3]
>   AND [tag4], ...) OR ...

And even

> [tag1] AND ([tag2] OR [tag3])

I need that because I'm looking for interesting questions and I have to search for each tag separately.

Comment: Please have a look at the related questions over there --->. There are currently quite a few issues doing complex searches.

Answer (score 27):

Search for `[tag1] or [tag2]`, e.g. [[support] or [feature-request]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+or+feature-request).

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: uh, why are you doing `[or]` when just plain "or" works fine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncrustify%20or%20undef

Comment: @JeffAtwood You don't get the page you linked from searching for `[uncrustify] or [undef]`, which [Nick says is intentional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115744/150235). Searching using `[uncrustify] [or] [undef]` does get you to that page, but apparently not intentionally.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - Tim is correct.  Searching for `[tag1] or [tag2]` results in a listing of all posts tagged with both `[tag1]` and `[tag2]` containing the word `or`, leading to [this `/search` page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?  q=%5Buncrustify%5D+or+%5Bundef%5D). Searching for `[tag1] [or] [tag2]` leads to [the `/tagged` page you linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncrustify+or+undef) I've edited the answer back to the solution that Waiwai, Nick, Tim Stone, and I have found.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D+or+%5Bsearch%5D works fine now.

Comment: This answer does not support what the OP and I are looking for. I have not found a way to search for tags `regex` and (`javascript` or `perl`), e.g. `[regex] and ([javascript] or [perl])`, or alternatively `([regex] [javascript]) or ([regex] [perl])`

Answer (score 10):

I've found my answer here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: Most of us search by using the 'search' box, not by appending our query to the `/tagged` URL.