# Searching for or (with or without pseudo-tag) with other search criteria does not work in search box

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

I've been looking for a way to search questions with one tag or another applied to it.

However, I *must* use the search box because I also wish to search for questions that have no answers applied to them (`answers:0`) and I can't apply that filter in the `questions/tagged` url (to my knowledge).

Additionally, I want to order by newest questions that meet this criteria.

That said, I came across the question "[Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)" which links to the blog post "[Tags AND Tags OR Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/)", which states at the bottom (**emphasis Jeff's**):

> **Anywhere on Stack Overflow you can specify a tag, you now specify multiple tags with or without the or clause.**

That said, the search bar is definitely someplace I can specify a tag.

If I put the following in the search bar:

```
[c#] or [c#-4.0] answers:0
```

It give's me the following result:

[image: Search results for "[c#] or [c#-4.0] answers:0" on StackOverflow]

Which seems to contradict Jeff's statement.  If anything, *at least* 648 results should be returned as per the second line under the "Use fewer words" suggestion.

I've also tried the `or` pseudo-tag, with no success:

[image: Search results for "[c#] [or] [c#-4.0] answers:0" on StackOverflow]

Answer (score 1):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), the search box only offers an `AND` search at the moment for tags.

However, you can achieve what you want via the Unanswered -> **No Answers** route, specifying any tags you want, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23+or+c%23-4.0?tab=noanswers

This will give you [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) OR [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) that have no answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't address the problem; I want to order by newest questions that meet this criteria (I've updated the question) to reflect that, so the url route still doesn't work.

Comment: @casperOne - in that case what you want isn't currently supported.

Comment: If you have the time, could you update or delete your answer given that I've updated the question?  That way, I can either accept (or not, in the case of it being not supported).