# Creating link to search query on StackOverflow in Markdown editor is incorrect

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperlink button breaks some URLs when automatically undoing URL encoding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153278/hyperlink-button-breaks-some-urls-when-automatically-undoing-url-encoding)

I am running across this issue trying to post the following links in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111816/searching-for-or-with-or-without-pseudo-tag-with-other-search-criteria-does-no).

Basically, the url I want to insert is:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bor%5D+%5Bc%23-4.0%5D+answers%3A0&submit=search

But when I enter it into the Markdown editor (through CTRL-L) I get:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc#%5D%20%5Bor%5D%20%5Bc#-4.0%5D%20answers:0&submit=search

Which is completely different.

I've come across other similar issues for the editor, but neither of them address this specific issue:

- [The Markdown editor chokes on $ characters in URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11943/the-markdown-editor-chokes-on-characters-in-urls)
- [URL shows differently on copy-paste](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42724/url-shows-differently-on-copy-paste)

Note, I'm not looking to display the URL as-is (otherwise, I'd simply insert the raw URL), but rather, create a link with specific text comprising the link.