# Logical-OR for tag filtering

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

At the moment, the way we can filter questions by tags allows us to request either the presence of a single tag (like `[c++]`), or the *intersection*, i.e. the simultaneous presence of all of several tags (like `[c++] [java]`). That is, composition is a logical AND.

Would it be possible to also have a logical-OR operator that allows us to select the *union* of questions that are tagged with *any one of* a collection of tags, like `[c++] ||  [java]`?

This would make it a lot more convenient to keep tabs on all questions that might be of interest.

Comment: @Mat: No, this is no duplicate, as we don't want to search, we just want it displayed.

Comment: @Xeo: sorry, I'm completely failing at understanding that. Where do you want to put that or'ed selection?

Comment: Is this a request for the per-site search, or for the tag filters at http://stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Mat: Nvm me, I misunderstood how that pseudo search tag was to be used! :)

Comment: @Xeo It's functionally the same as searching, though. A tag-only search takes you to the same page as clicking on that tag.