# Searching questions belonging to atleast one of the searched tags

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

In stackoverflow how do we search questions which are being tagged by atleast one of the tags mentioned in search box.
For eg
seaching `[java][javascript]` gives all question which have been tagged both, but I need either one of them.

Thanks

Comment: thanks Rob, i don't know why but i am not able to add comment to your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature does already exist. Simply add `or` between the tags:

Live example: [`[java] or [javascript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+javascript).

Comment: @Jeff Why did you remove the square braces in my answer? Without these, the search query will **[fail](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+or+[javascript])**.

Comment: we're fixing this, it was never intended to work that way