# How can I OR tags without having to modify the URL?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

As a SO user, I'd like to see the list of questions tagged with **any** of a set of tags (let's say `mysql` and `sql`) order by descending date and being able to filter out all accepted answers.

I couldn't find a way to do that so far, but I did get close enough to get the previous result but without filtering the accepted answers:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+sql?sort=newest
```

Additionally, I noticed that by doing this the tags on the right get ORed like in the picture:

[image]

However, I couldn't find any other way to do that other than directly typing the previous URL in the browser.

Is there any better way to do this?

PS: I looked for an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search), but it didn't help

Comment: As the answer to the proposed duplicate suggests, you just need to enter `[mysql] [or] [sql]` in the search box.

Comment: Interesting. This is better than typing in the address bar. However, the question still applies. How can I filter out the accepted answers? `[mysql] [or] [sql] hasaccepted:0` won't work as expected

Comment: No idea, why would you ever want to do that anyway?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Just to see what questions have not yet been satisfied with an appropriate answer (in order to try to provide one) about the tags that are interesting to me.

Comment: Who cares if it's been answered? If you have a better answer, answer it anyway. If the existing answer is already good, upvote it. If you don't know the answer and it's something you care about, learn something. I try to go through the answers to questions with tags that interest me on a daily basis.

Comment: It's too bad nobody seems to be reading [the faqs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79357/150562)...

Comment: It is not my intention to discuss personal interests, only software requirements. Users should have easy access to unanswered questions about the tags that interest them (there is a huge `Unanswered` button and even a `hasaccepted:0` search tip). Stack Overflow is just missing a way to combine ORed interesting tags and the `hasaccepted:0` search tip.