# Searching for questions tagged A *or* B

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

How can you search for questions tagged A **or** B?

Searching for `A B` finds questions that contain `A` or `B`, but not tagged as such.

While searching for `[A] [B]` finds questions that are tagged `A` **and** `B`. I've tried adding `or` between those without any luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/A+OR+B
```

Real example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery+OR+javascript (`javascript` OR `jQuery`)

You can also use this in the search textbox: `[a] [or] [b]`

Comment: Thanks. Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Qtax. I don't... It's documented  now... `:)`

Comment: Apparently it's documented in some random [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/), I was hoping for something on the site it self.