# How do you search for [tag1] or [tag2]

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

I've seen a number of questions about how to search for two keywords using AND, since OR is the default.  I've also seen questions about how to search for questions containing two tags ([tag][tag2]).  What I want to do is search for questions containing either [tag1] or [tag2].  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - this does look like a duplicate of that question.  Not sure why my searching didn't turn it up.

Comment: @jadarnel27 The title as it is doesn't make sense, and it is not what the OP is asking. There is no need for searching for "[tag] or [tag]"; the search result would be the same as searching for [tag].

Comment: @kiamlaluno Just because it's not exactly correct doesn't mean people wouldn't search for it.  The body of the question makes it clear what the OP means.  I'm not married to this revision, though.  Feel free to change it back if you feel it's more useful the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Sure can.

```
[tag1][or][tag2]
```

Comment: How 'bout that.  [or] must be a blacklisted tag, otherwise this wouldn't work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yeah, Jeff confirmed that in a comment a while back. Can't find it right now, but I'm certain I saw it this week.