# Searching for questions tagged with PHP or MySQL or JavaScript or

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, search

If you want to see question related to PHP you just need to type `[PHP]` in search box, and if you want to see any question which are tag by PHP **and** MySQL then I can search with `[PHP][mysql]`.

But what if I want to see questions tagged either PHP **or** MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search \[tag1\] OR \[tag2\]]([Search \[tag1\] OR \[tag2\]]([Search \[tag1\] OR \[tag2\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53943))), [How do you search for \[tag1\] or \[tag2\]]([How do you search for \[tag1\] or \[tag2\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139530)), [Search for two tags (OR, not AND)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102484), [Use OR operator in tagged question search?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114642), etc.

Comment: This should be with support tag and not feature-request still Community user [thinks otherwise](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16739)

Comment: @CRUSADER: i dont know that this is can be achieve like this. Hence updated by post and tags. Thanks

Comment: @CRUSADER - Have a look at this for [why does community user rejected your edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/187824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or` between two tags like this: [[php] or [mysql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+mysql)