# How to see questions with one of a set of tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

If you put some tags inside the search field you will get the questions which include those tags. However, I want to search the questions which include those tags **or just one of those tags**. How can achieve it?

Comment: @hims056 That question is for the old query engine.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - See it's [linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/53943?lq=1) lots of duplicates, most are closed as a duplicate of it.

Comment: The answer in that question is obsolete. `[tag1] [or] [tag2]` works, but it is not longer nessecary to do that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - Then it's duplicate of other linked questions. E.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192049/187824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `or`:

```
[tag1] or [tag2]
```

Example:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+or+discussion
Searches for all questions tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). Of course it also finds questions tagged with both [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)