# OR behaviour on tags in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

Imagine I like `C#` and `SQL`, I'm thinking why does stack overflow show me all questions tagged with `C#` **AND** `SQL`? What I may like to see is questions tagged either with `C#` **OR** SQL.

In fact I like to be able to choose this behavior myself, it's really helpful if I see what I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%5Bc%23%5D+OR+%5Bsql%5D - the best hidden feature on SO.

Comment: really? yeah it exists :) thanks man, cool