# Is it possible to build search query combining AND and OR operators?

Tags: feature-request, search

I've searched through many suggested questions, including this [possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2) but haven't found straight answer.
I've dig through Our model and Advanced search tips, of course.

So, is it possible to build expressions like this and how?

```
([kerberos] OR [gssapi]) AND ([ios] OR [iphone])
```

And, subquestion, sort of: Is it possible to suscribe e-mail or RSS new question notification of such search somehow? I've found this option only for single tags...

Although I've read instructions about how to write good questions, help me improve my question if you feel it is needed, please.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm interesting case.  I do support this, but there has to be a break between the `OR` tag sets for them to be treated as 2 searches, typically a word, phrase or option in the middle.  I'll take a look at the AND case here later next week, but now here's a temporary workaround until then:
`[kerberos] or [gssapi] "" [ios] or [iphone]`, [you can try it here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkerberos%5D%20or%20%5Bgssapi%5D%20%22%22%20%5Bios%5D%20or%20%5Biphone%5D).

Comment: @Cole did you read my answer? I thought the "I'll take a look" and "temporary workaround" were very, very clear.