# search terms with AND and OR operators and parentheses

Tags: feature-request, support, search

I'd like to know if it is possible to use search strings like this:

> resource AND (allocation OR scheduling)

I'm aware of [this kind of question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191845/is-it-possible-to-build-search-query-combining-and-and-or-operators) but it's not a duplicate because I'd like to have boolean operators with regular search terms, not only with tags. I also tried to find information on the advanced search tips, but didn't find something in that direction.

Comment: If you have a `+` before the words, such as `+apples +oranges`, then that will do what you want... Not too sure though

Comment: tested here but it doesn't work. thanks anyway.

Comment: Wow... Area 51 got more love than this place!

Comment: Search terms with AND , OR, and parentheses would be really useful. For example, I have not found a way to search for tags `regex` AND (`javascript` OR `perl`), e.g. `[regex] and ([javascript] or [perl])`, or equivalent `([regex] [javascript]) or ([regex] [perl])`