# Use OR operator in tagged question search?

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

When performing a *basic* search, the [default used operator is `OR`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search). For example, if I search for `kitchen operator`, results will contain the word `kitchen` or the word `operator`:

[image: kitchen operator]

To use the `AND` operator, you need to search for `+kitchen +operator`. Fine.

---

Now if I want to perform a tag search, for instance `[c#] [sql]`, the operator used is obviously `AND`:

[image: c# sql]

There are newer question that are tagged only [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but they aren't displayed here.

So my question is: is it possible to use the `OR` operator in a **tag** search? If it's not, then this question is falling in the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) ones. :)