# Does the search feature really do an AND?

Tags: support, search

It took me a while to find the information, that the search already shall do a AND like mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search/161776#161776).

I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%22generics%22+null) `[java] "generics" null` and it feels like OR. Why doesn't it work without `"` at generics by the way (side question)?

Comment: Looking through the result, many of them contains different forms of the root `generate`: `generation`, `generics`, `general`, `generalize`,...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+null returns 193,295 results, where as http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+null+%22generics%22 returns only 826 results; think it's pretty clear that it's an "and".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by comments and the other answer it really is AND. The real answer I found now is this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%22generics%22+%22null%22): `[java] "generics" "null"`

I don't know why I didn't try that yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling the search is looking for similar words, as it is highlighting the word **generally** which I assume the search engine thinks is close to the word *generics*. Adding quotes around *generics* tells the search to look for that **exact** word, not to test against similar words which is why you're getting different results there.

It definitely is doing an AND, it's just when you leave the quotes out it's not ANDing on the word "generics".

Comment: Well, it *is* ANDing on "generics" ... `AND CONTAINS(FORMSOF(THESAURUS, 'generics'))` :P

Comment: And that's why it felt like OR, because it really is something like `java AND (generics OR generate OR generation OR general OR generalize)`, but that's OK, the real solution is my own answer, i.e. to use quotes on the second search term `null`, too.