# Allow boolean searches

Tags: feature-request, search

I read about adding tag names and stuff in search terms, but how can I search for **two** keywords in `AND` fashion? (I.e. both keywords appear in some discussion, not as an expression.)

For example: say I want to see all discussions that are about both apples and oranges.

Comment: Tis a dupe, but I can't find it right now

Comment: I'm puzzled. AND is the default. Test (all questions with bounty and support): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+bounty

Comment: @John: I think @nikos is talking about keyword searching, not tag searching.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Ok, than it is a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/can-we-have-search-default-to-and-instead-of-or

Comment: dupe? that referenced thread is philosophical, and talks about TAGs not keywords. Try it, search for "IHTMLElement hidden" and you'll get a jumble of results that have only one keyword, there is no algorithm bringing discussions with both keywords near the top

It's such a basic principle of search I must be missing something?

Comment: @nikos: Hear hear! The utter lack of an "and" keyword makes the search intolerable and/or useless sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible. See [Jeff's explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/how-do-i-make-search-return-results-that-actually-contain-all-the-search-terms/35646#35646).