# Search with and operator

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can we have search default to “AND” instead of “OR”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/can-we-have-search-default-to-and-instead-of-or)
>   [Why OR operator by default in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search)
>   [Why search is so bad on SO ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21047/why-search-is-so-bad-on-so)

When you enter 2 words in the search it defaults to the OR operator, why not to the AND operator (as most search engines do)?

Is it possible to use the AND operator?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search

Comment: Don't close this please, it's the feature-request for this functionality.  the dupe isn't, so it won't show in Jeff's feature-request search.

Comment: @Lance. Since this already can be done I see no need for the feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search/35645#35645

Comment: Please don't close. As already explained, this is not a dupe. This is a *feature request*.

The current way is obscure and not supported. If you use "word" and "word2" and use the pagination the search query is messed up.

Also, if you read, my feature feature is simple: make the default in  the search to AND not OR.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this, but it's obscure.

Quotes trigger strict matching, like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22perl+array%22

But that strict matching search mode is **typically only used for phrases**. If you want it in words, you have to use quotes around each word:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22xts%22%20%22mode%22

compare with results from non-quoted version

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xts+mode

Answer (score 1):

From what I've tried, it looks like "AND" is not supported in the SO search.

I would like to see the behavior change as well. Better yet, how about support for boolean operators?

However, the usual answer for questions on SO search is "use Google".