# Search not keeping AND when changing tabs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, tabs

I've found that using the feature Jeff describes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35597/search-with-and-operator/35644#35644) about **AND** searching on words works great, but when it first comes up it's on the 'relevance' tab:

[alt text http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/3434/search1d.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/3434/search1d.png)

Then when I hit the 'newest' tab, it loses the **AND**, so I have to manually modify the url to get the 'newest' tab on an AND search.

[alt text http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/6961/search2.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/6961/search2.png)

Seems like search could be implemented to keep the **AND**.

**EDIT:**  I've removed the display components that some people couldn't handle, and have added the freehand circles, though frankly I'm burnt out on that meme, since people have decided they'll now downvote if you don't have them.  When a meme get's pushed that far, it's no fun anymore.

Comment: -1 for screenshot with no circles and what appears to be several GreaseMonkey scripts with a clock (wtf?) and whatnot. I don't know what I'm looking at...

Comment: Sorry my title bar scares you, the search information is all there and the same.  No time for freehand circles today.

Comment: @kobi, check out the great script here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23656/greasemonkey-script-to-gold-plate-sofu

Comment: You can't be sured that's why it's being downvoted...

Comment: @Downvoter, read the first comment

Comment: @Lance, that does not mean he actually downvoted you, nor that anyone else did it for that reason... look, look: "-1 because I want to" (did your score change?)

Comment: For the record, I removed my downvote days ago when the images where updated. Not because the circles, but because it features so many foreign features it was just confusing. Also, a grease monkey script can mess with the page, so submitting a bug report with it is irresponsible and should be discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in search input sanitization.

Fixing that also removes the requirement to use AND between quoted words as well.

Comment: We're onto you Atwood. You leave bugs around in order to eat up all the Meta bounty rep.

Comment: Congratulations, you are the Winner.