# Using OR condition when searching with tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

I already read 2 questions regarding search on meta:

- [Why OR operator by default in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search)
- [Can we have search default to "AND" instead of "OR"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/can-we-have-search-default-to-and-instead-of-or)

But what I am looking for is something different (Or am I confused?!!). Here is what I need:

Lets say, I am interested in questions with two tags - C# & xml. I usually use "[C#]" in the search field  and get all the questions with C# tag. Similarly, I get all the questions tagged xml when I key "[xml]".

Now, If I enter "[C#][xml]" - I get all the questions where both C# and xml are present. My question is - Is there a way to display all questions with C# and xml? Here is one possible example. I may want questions tagged asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2 and asp.net-mvc-3.

If I key in all of them in square brace, I get only the questions having all the tags. But I need questions having any of these tags.

Do we have an operator like [C#]||[xml] ? Or is there another why to get what I need?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search \[tag1\] OR \[tag2\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

Comment: @waiwai933 .. Thanks for the link .. Going thru it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags), it is possible to use OR when you’re searching via the URL query:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 or xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#%20or%20xml)

Note that you have to escape # as %23 because otherwise Stack Overflow gets confused:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c# or xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#%20or%20xml)

yields a search for the [c] tag.